# Trigger en SQL. Cursores

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy empezando con cursores en SQL y tengo esta sentencia:

```
CREATE TRIGGER recogida
BEFORE INSERT ON Recoge
FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
  diferencia INTEGER;
 BEGIN
SELECT (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM(:new.fecha - fecha))) INTO diferencia FROM Recoge WHERE    (:new.IdPersonal = IdPersonal AND :new.Año = Año);
IF (diferencia < 1) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20600, :new.fecha || 'Un trabajador no puede serle asignado un pedido con menos de 1 hora de diferencia');
END IF;
END;
```

Y me da el siguiente error:

```
la recuperación exacta devuelve un número mayor de filas que el solicitado
```

Entiendo que debería de utilizar un cursor ya que select me devuelve más de un registro, pero estoy bastante perdida con ello, ya que todo lo que pruebo da algún tipo de error sintáctico. Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!